# use RequiredFieldValidator and Watermark property

Tags: javascript, asp.net, watermark, requiredfieldvalidator

i use this code in aspx page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Search" runat="server" ToolTip="Search..." Text="Search..." onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Search...';" onfocus="if (this.value=='Search...') this.value='';"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSearch" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Search" ErrorMessage="please insert text" ValidationGroup="Search" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

but i use *Text="Search"* in textbox for use Watermark property in textbox. please help me for use property and RequiredFieldValidator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set `InitialValue = "Search..."`

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSearch" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="Search" ErrorMessage="please insert text" 
    ValidationGroup="Search" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="None"
    InitialValue="Search...">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Doing this, error message will be shown unless `Search` contains something different to `Search...`

Comment: thx. and i use RegularExpressionValidator: ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*". please help me for this.

Comment: @Babak Saeedi: not trying to be rude, but you may consider to create a separated question for that since it's not related to your original question. It's common to end up answering 100 not related questions on comment area and that's not the idea.